# Wireless networking continuously in "connecting" state after Suspend

Tags: wireless, networking, suspend

Ubuntu 14.04
I've searched extensively for a similar issue, the closest I can find is where the output for nmcli nm returns "sleep" for the "state" key. However, my output (when the problem starts) has "connecting" as the entry.

The problem appears as such: It will try to connect to a wireless network for ~10-15 seconds, fail, then move on to the next network. This repeats. After a fail, the wifi popup shows "Disconnected from Network X", where X is whatever network I was connected to previously. This will show, for instance, my home network even if I'm miles away and the Home network is not in the wireless network lists.

Very comfortable running commands and such, just want to get this working :(.

Ubuntu is currently running dual-booted on my HP Envy.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really a solution, but, when this happens to me I work around it by restarting network manager `sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem since upgrading to 14.04, and have yet to find a solution.

Upon system resume, after typing in Ubuntu pwd, it attempts to reconnect to the wifi network. It says "connecting" and eventually brings up the credentials/pwd prompt for that wifi network (which has a saved pwd, which hasn't changed, and is still correctly entered), but it never reconnects even if I retype the wifi network's pwd. However, it can successfully connect to the other wifi network, just not to the one to which it was connected before closing the lid.

I tried restarting network manager, nmcli nm, removing lightdm, adding SUSPEND_MODULES= to /etc/pm/config.d/config - which worked once, but only once ([http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2004690]), and several other suggestions, but nothing works other than a reboot (occasionally logging off worked too) or remembering to manually disconnect from the wifi network before closing the lid.

What a pain...especially for non-techies who also use this computer. I'd really appreciate any suggestions which might actually solve this problem once and for all - thanks! :)