# Wireless won't connect after resume - adapter is not asleep

Tags: wireless, networking, suspend

Running 14.04 on a Samsung N150. I am having the same problem as described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528496/wireless-networking-continuously-in-connecting-state-after-suspend)

To reiterate, this is NOT the '[adapter sleeping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04)' problem; it sees the network(s) and starts trying to connect immediately but never succeeds. Deleting the network and re-connecting doesn't work. The only solution I've found is to reboot.

One update to this (still not got anything to work, but thanks for the pointers): When it is in the failing state, if I turn off the wireless router, that network **continues to appear** in the list of available networks, and the computer will try and connect to it! If I delete it from the list of networks then it does disappear. When I turn the router back on then it reappears but I can't connect to it. Don't know if that is a clue at all?

Comment: Having the same issue... would love to hear if anyone has any work arounds. For what it's worth, after removing the wifi network from the saved connections, then resetting the router, I can connect. But as soon as I suspend and resume it does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and

```
killall wpa_supplicant
```

only worked for a while before it became totally useless.

After some update the resume thing caused a clickpad failure along with the wireless thing and installing fglrx fixed both issues:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem since upgrading to 14.04, and have yet to find a solution.

Upon system resume, after typing in Ubuntu pwd, it attempts to reconnect to the wifi network. It says "connecting" and eventually brings up the credentials/pwd prompt for that wifi network (which has a saved pwd, which hasn't changed, and is still correctly entered), but it never reconnects even if I retype the wifi network's pwd. However, it can successfully connect to the other wifi network, just not to the one to which it was connected before closing the lid.

I tried restarting network manager, nmcli nm, removing lightdm, adding SUSPEND_MODULES= to /etc/pm/config.d/config - which worked once, but only once ([http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2004690]), and several other suggestions, but nothing works other than a reboot (occasionally logging off worked too) or remembering to manually disconnect from the wifi network before closing the lid.

What a pain...especially for non-techies who also use this computer. I'd really appreciate any suggestions which might actually solve this problem once and for all - thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I just posted that nothing had worked in a comment, but then I read [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230072) which suggested some things, and at the bottom this:

`sudo killall wpa_supplicant`

That did it. I was then able to reconnect to my home wifi network. Funny thing is, after rebooting and trying the process again, I did not have to use the command, reconnecting after suspend/resume just worked. :/

If you needed to run this command each time though, you could combine the command above with [this other solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04) which suggests a bash script to run after each wake.

Good luck.

Comment: And just another test... when I remove the connection from the existing list and repeat the whole process the reconnection after suspend/resume fails again. Running the command above _after_ suspending/resuming seemed to fix things again, but this is clearly just a workaround.